# using a given wavefunction to find particle properties

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, particle-physics

Let's say we have a given wavefunction and we want to find a particle that will fulfill the properties for that wavefunction. How can we do that? Is it possible? I was thinking of using Schrodinger's equation.. would that work?

(please tell me if there is anything wrong with this question so I can fix it!)

Comment: Many things are possible given enough money. If there is a crazy wave-function, we may find difficult to implement it. Can't you be more specific on which wave-functions you think, or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Could you be more specific? By wavefunction do you mean the state vector or the state vector in position representation. In the first case I think it would not be possible. You could be given the vector $(1 \quad 0)$, and you would only know that it is a two state system.

Answer (score 1):

The wavefunction depends on the environment - e.g. width of a square well in one dimension - so that you should not be looking for a particle, but an environment with a particle in it.

Given that you are interested in this as a theoretical project/thought experiment then depending on what you want in your wave function it may be possible to find a potential (e.g. square well, harmonic well, 2 D box etc.) that will give something close to the function you want.

It depends because if, for example, you want the wavefunction to look like a square wave then you are going to be dissappointed because wavefunctions need to be continuous and have continuous gradients.

I am not aware of a general solution to this problem. It is a type of ['inverse problem'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem) where the desired solution is a wavefunction and we have to try to figure out the potential responsible for it. The other way around - given an arbitrary potential calculate wavefunctions - is relatively straightforward.

I think if you are interested in a 1-D wavefunction then I would begin by using the shooting method ([reference here](http://www.physics.buffalo.edu/phy410-505-2009/topic5/lec-5-1.pdf) and [reference here](http://theorie.physik.uni-konstanz.de/juan/numik4/docs/shoot-Schroed.pdf)) to calculate one dimensional wavefunctions for a range of different potentials to see what was possible.

Comment: This is not an appropriate answer. If you are not sure, then, first ask what is meant in the question (which is indeed quite undefined), and then answer.

Comment: @Sofia - good comment - but I thought if I answered the two different possible cases then it might provide a useful answer for T Abraham or T Abraham could leave a comment to get back and explain more about what they are interested in.

Comment: I am looking into the second possibilty

Comment: I would like to hopefully use 2-d wavefunctions

Comment: You may just have to solve 2D Schroedinger equation for that. I would suggest you look up particle in 2D box or particle in 2D harmonic potential as possible types of solution that might be useful to you.